# Get browser URL from two level depth iframe

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

There is an `iframe` in an other `iframe`. I would like to get the browser's URL *(in example: http://test)* from the second `iframe`.

```
//browser URL: http://test <-- I need this URL

<iframe src="http://level1">
    <iframe src="http://level2">
        <!-- some content -->
    </iframe>
</iframe>
```

I tried `document.referrer` but it gives back the first iframe's URL:

```
<iframe src="http://level1">
    <iframe src="http://level2">
        console.log(document.referrer); //It gives back http://level1
    </iframe>
</iframe>
```

**UPDATE:**

The `top.location.href` doesn't work because there are different domains. Different the browser, the first and the second iframe domain. *(our website - adserver - third-party website)*

Comment: If all the pages share the same domain, you can get the URL of the topmost window in any `iframe` like so: `top.location.href`.

Comment: There are two different domain. I get error message: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.firsturl.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://secondurl.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Comment: Well guess you are out of luck. Same Origin Policy will not allow you to do it.

Comment: Simply impossible. You can't acces iframe content which is not from your domain.

Comment: So it's impossible.. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said it is in general not possible from cross-domain iframes, but in the case of Chrome you can use `window.location.ancestorOrigins` that will give you the "top level url" and a list of all the domains if you are in several iframes no matter if they are cross-domain or not.